# Java is not reading a variable I am passing to it after the user modifies it

Tags: java, methods, switch-statement

I have a really long problem.  I am creating a bank account and setting the balance to 0.  If the user chooses to withdraw or deposit money to the account, the balance never changes.  I choose to show the balance and it still says 0.  This is probably a no brainer but I am spent right now.  Here is my long code(The switch statement is in my main class and the methods are in an object class):

```
public class MyProgram2{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    String menu, outputString, poo;
    int option = 1;
    int id = 0;
    double balance = 0, amount = 0;
    Account acc = new Account();


    menu ="\n\t1  Create Account and ID" + 
            "\n\t2  Check balance" +
            "\n\t3  Withdraw" +
            "\n\t4  Deposit" + 
            "\n\t5  Get account ID" +
            "\n\t6  Display Account Info" +

            "\n\t0  Quit\n\n\n";

    System.out.println(menu);
    System.out.println("\tEnter your selection:  ");
    option = scan.nextInt();

    while (option != 0) {

            switch (option) {

            case 1: //Create an account and set ID
                        System.out.print("Enter Your Account ID to create account:\t");
                        id = input.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("Account created!");
                        break;

            case 2:     //check balance
                        acc.checkBalance(balance);
                        break;

            case 3:     //withdraw money
                        acc.withdraw(balance, amount);
                        break;

            case 4: //deposit money
                        acc.deposit(balance, amount);
                        break;

            case 5:     //get account id
                        acc.getID(id);
                        break;

            case 7:     //display account info
                        System.out.print("option 7");
                        break;

            default: outputString = "\nInvalid Selection\n";
                        System.out.println(outputString);
                        break;

        }
    System.out.println(menu);
    System.out.print("\tEnter your selection:   ");
    option = scan.nextInt();    
    }
```

And these are the methods I am calling:

```
public class Account{
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

public Account(){
}

public void getID(int id){
    System.out.println("Your account ID is:\t" + id);
}

public void checkBalance(double balance){
    System.out.println("Your balance is:\t$" + balance);
}

public double withdraw(double amount, double balance){
    System.out.println("How much do you want to withdraw?:\t$");
    amount = input.nextDouble();
    balance -= amount;
    return balance;
}

public double deposit(double amount, double balance){
    System.out.println("How much do you want to deposit?:\t");
    amount = input.nextDouble();
    balance += amount;
    return balance;
}

public void getAccountInfo(int id, double balance){

}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable

```
double balance
```

cannot be passed as a reference. It does a copy so when you try to manipulate it, it won't affect the original that you pass as an argument. You need to update the value using the return value that you have in the function.

In order to make it work, you should do:

```
case 4: //deposit money

// note here that you need to update the balance variable using the return value that
// you put in the function
balance = acc.deposit(balance, amount);
break;
```

**Note**: Your design separating the balance from the Account class is not ideal per @Psyrus's answer. You should keep the balance as part of the Account class. The reason being that balance is part of the account and if your program grows to handle multiple accounts (just for the sake of examples), separating the variable balance from the account would create maintenance headache (imagine that with two instances of Account, you will have balance1 and balance2 variables (or whatever you will call it)  in MyProgram2, the main application). While I gave the cause of your problem in regards of variable passing, you should refactor your code to follow @Psyrus suggestion.

Comment: An alternative, if pass-by-reference effect was desired, would be to create a `DoubleHolder` object with a single public field. +1 for making this absolutely clear.

Comment: You are returning the balance but not using the return value at all, so the value is not getting updated. I will update the answer with sample code

Comment: + 1 for the good explanation with example nightmare. (and for mentioning me :D)

Comment: This works fine but it does not keep up with the balance.  ill withdraw 20 for -20 and then withdraw 30 and it will say -30, not -50.  Any ideas?

Comment: You need to do the same for the rest of the methods that use return value (such as withdraw()). I am just illustrating one example in deposit() so you would understand where you mistakes are. If you understand the the answer, you would be able to derive the rest.

Comment: I did change this to all the methods with returning value.  It does not work.  It will show deposits and withdraws until you deposit or withdraw again. EX: balance = 0.0. Withdraw 20, balance = -20.0. Desposit 10, balance = 10....not -10.  It should remember that it was -20 and add 10 to that, not return to zero...

Comment: You got your method mixed up in the parameter order. You pass balance, amount from MyProgram2, but your method takes amount, balance. You just need to make both of them the same. Example: public double withdraw(double amount, double balance) should be public double withdraw(double balance, double amount). Same with deposit

Answer (score 3):

You have your whole Account class set up but without the actual balance variable inside it. Move that variable from your program to your class and it should work. Upon looking further, you have kind of jumbled up bits between the two so do this:

```
public class MyProgram2{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    String menu, outputString, poo;
    int option = 1;
    int id = 0;
    Account acc = new Account();


    menu ="\n\t1  Create Account and ID" + 
        "\n\t2  Check balance" +
        "\n\t3  Withdraw" +
        "\n\t4  Deposit" + 
        "\n\t5  Get account ID" +
        "\n\t6  Display Account Info" +

        "\n\t0  Quit\n\n\n";

    do {

      System.out.println(menu);
      System.out.println("\tEnter your selection:  ");
      option = scan.nextInt();

      switch (option) {

        case 1: //Create an account and set ID
        System.out.print("Enter Your Account ID to create account:\t");
        id = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Account created!");
        break;

        case 2:     //check balance
        acc.checkBalance();
        break;

        case 3:     //withdraw money
        acc.withdraw();
        break;

        case 4: //deposit money
        acc.deposit();
        break;

        case 5:     //get account id
        acc.getID(id);
        break;

        case 7:     //display account info
        System.out.print("option 7");
        break;

        default: outputString = "\nInvalid Selection\n";
        System.out.println(outputString);
        break;

      }
    } while (option != 0);
  }
}

public class Account{

  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);    double balance = 0;

  public Account(){
  }

  public void getID(id){
    System.out.println("Your account ID is:\t" + id);
  }

  public void checkBalance(){
    System.out.println("Your balance is:\t$" + balance);
  }

  public double withdraw(){
    System.out.println("How much do you want to withdraw?:\t$");
    double amount = input.nextDouble();
    balance -= amount;
  }

  public double deposit(){
    System.out.println("How much do you want to deposit?:\t");
    double amount = input.nextDouble();
    balance += amount;
    return balance;
  }

  public void getAccountInfo(int id, double balance){

  }
}
```

That is one way of doing it, but like I say, your design is a bit of a cross between classes.  You should try to keep all properties for an object within that class and create functions for that class to obtain / modify the properties.  Printing to the user should be contained in the class responsible for giving the user the interface.

**Edit:** Oops forgot the while at the end of the do while loop...

Answer (score 2):

You just need to modify the instance you created like this:

```
public double deposit(){
    System.out.println("How much do you want to deposit?:\t");
    this.amount = input.nextDouble();
    this.balance += amount;
    return balance;
}
```

The `this keyword` refers to the object that is calling this method in this case `acc`, so `this.amount` will modify the `amount` for that instance.

In your current code, you are just modifying the `local variables`.

You also need to update your Account class to have the amount and balance attributes:

```
public class Account{
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
double balance = 0, amount = 0;
```

Comment: in what class is the THIS keyword found? It says it cannot find it

Comment: The this keyword is not a part of any class, it is just a keyword to refer to the instance calling the methods. It should work if you just do this.amount, this is in every method that is NOT static like the one you have.

Comment: @Josh see my updated answer you need to include the attributes in the Account class, so you can modify the instance.

Comment: Just tried this and it does not work.  It now recognizes THIS but after depositing or withdrawing it still says 0